# When new fields deployed from sandbox, how do I give acccess to guest site users?

Tags: administration, permissions

We created a web page for contact information.  When we deployed it to production, all the new fields were hidden from all users.  I set the access to visible for all users, however my guest site users license for the web access does not have access to the new fields?

I have verified the Guest Site Profile has access to visualforce page, controller and custom object (Create, Read).

When you display at the field security, there isn't a way to allow guest site users access to these new fields?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Charles. What kind of license do your guest users have assigned?

Comment: The users are web users with no licenses.  Salesforce assigns them a guest site license.  This is how they control which objects, visualforce pages, controllers are accessed by the website users.

Answer (score 5):

**I found the answer**
After you create the Site.  Click on Public Access.  It will give you access to the Guest site profile.  Go the security section and add the security access to the additional fields.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a global permission set (one without a license), assign the appropriate field level security, then assign the permission set to the guest user. Site --> public access settings --> guest profile --> view users --> Guest User.